# levelplot stop working after update: error message

Tags: r, raster, levelplot, rastervis

I've updated all the libraries in Rstudio and now, all the plot that I used to make with rasterVis::level plot are not working anymore. This is the error message that I received.. Any idea?thanks

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited 
method for function ‘xmin’ for signature ‘"Extent"’
```

Comment: The latest update of the terra package includes a change in the package dependencies, causing warnings and errors on the rasterVis side: https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_rasterVis.html. I am working on the code of rasterVis to adapt it to this change.

Comment: Thank you! In the meanwhile, as a workaround,  I've reinstalled the older version through install_version("rasterVis", version = "0.49", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")